# Phonegap getCurrentPosition() callbacks don't fire in AVD

Tags: cordova

I'm building a native app with Phonegap and have run into a problem with getCurrentPosition(). It was working fine yesterday but today when I started developing the callbacks for getting the location don't fire. My syntax is like so

```
showMessage('geo started');
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationSuccess, onLocationError);

function onLocationSuccess(position){
        showMessage('geo success');
}
function onLocationError(position){
        showMessage('location error');
}
```

I have a debug message right before I call the navigator, and in each callback (onLocationSuccess and onLocationError). The first debug is shown, neither of the callback debugs happen, leading me to believe the navigator function either isn't getting called properly or just isn't calling its callbacks. Any reason why this would occur?

Comment: What OS are you currently testing this on? Are you using the Geolocation Plugin? What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: developing in windows 8. running in an AVD (android virtual device)

Comment: Are you using the Geolocation Plugin? If you are, try removing it and just using the HTML5 Geolocation API instead, it's the same syntax but there have been some issues with the PhoneGap Geolocation Plugin on Android. They actually are deprecating it in the next release and advise using just the HTML5 Geolocation API.

Comment: just tried it on a physical device and it works, so it only doesn't work in the virtual device. that's a serious pain for testing though, is there any way to figure out what's causing that?

Comment: I remember having a tough time with this on an AVD as well. I had to go in and manually feed coordinates through Eclipse